# Find all assignments to variable

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse has an easy way to find all references to a variable, but is there a quick way to only look for assignments?

Comment: What would be really nice is the ReSharper way of doing it, with little icons signifying reads or writes in the search results.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Quick? Hm... Find all references with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then filter in the `Search` view (results) via the View menu (dropdown triangle). You can select `Reads` there to filter these.

**Shortcut**: Cursor to the variable, menu `Search > Write Access > Workspace`. No keybinding assigned by default, but you can do this as usual (`Preferences > General > Keys`).

Comment: I had to select `Reads`, not `Writes`.

Comment: You should be selecting `Reads` instead of `Writes` since the menu in the Search view allows you to select what to exclude, not what to include.

Answer (score 38):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> shows all usages of a variable, with different icons for read and write references.

You can also set different colors for read and write occurrences of the selected variable (in the right part of the editor). These colors are set in Eclipse preferences, in "General -> Editors -> Text editors -> Annotations". There is "Occurences" and "Write occurences". I set the same color, slightly darker for "Write occurence", so I can easily spot write occurences, without any key stroke.

Comment: Looks like that's for java only. Doesn't work for me in Eclipse C/C++

Comment: This one is best for me -- it immediately causes the Search view to open up with a nice, flat view of the results.  `Shift-Ctrl-G`, on the other hand, takes a moment to come up and shows a view that doesn't show the actual matches: it just shows where the matches are, and I have to double-click that location and scan the actual file.  `Ctrl+Shift+U` shows me what I need to see right away.

Comment: Nice touch at the end about color setting. Useful shortcut for faster coding

Comment: This only searches within the current file! Not really helpful for complex projects.

Comment: As jack already mentioned, Shift-Ctrl-U ist a *file local* search only! Not as useful as You might expect...

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+Alt+U` finds all the references within a class (local references) for a particular variable, on my ubuntu machine.